# font mismatch : article class vs book class

Tags: fonts, article

I normally use latex to create a private pdf notebook of solutions (e.g. ch01.tex).
However, I also use it to create a convenient pdf listing of the definitions + theorems in a 
book (e.g. summary.tex).  In ch01.tex, my only alteration of the default font settings are the following preamble commands:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

In summary.tex, since I need the book class to enable chapter headings, my 
preamble begins:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Unfortunately, the book class' normalsize 12pt is apparently smaller than the 
article class' 12 pt.  To compensate, I currently (*kludgily*) use the following
command in summary.tex

```
\large
```

A cleaner solution would be to place command(s) in summary.tex (either in its preamble or just after \begin{document})
that invoke the exact same font that is normally used in the article class.

HOW DO I DO THIS?

Comment: you should have some differences in article and book document. please provide small but complete documents (one article, one book) with short dummy text which reproduce your problem.

Comment: `\documentclass[...,12pt,...]{article}` loads [`size12.clo`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo?view=co), while `\documentclass[...,12pt,...]{book}` loads [`bk12.clo`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo?view=co). These two files set the font sizes. You can compare them, they are similar in most respects, except for some margin settings.

Comment: @Zarko  Good tip.  I am attempting to construct mwe's to reproduce problem.  Will place second comment directed to you when my original query updated with mwe's.

Comment: @Werner Interesting comment, the plot thickens.  See my comment/reply to Zarko.  Will also place 2nd comment directed to you.

Comment: article and book are not just similar, they are generated from the same source file, and the font loading code is identical. If \large in one document is \normalsize in the other, presumably one is using the default 10pt option and one is using the 12pt option.

Comment: have you used a font command as if with an argument, such as `\small{this}` or `\large{that}` ?

Comment: @Zarko see edited query.  I now consider this (original) query resolved.  Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Werner see edited query.  I now consider this (original) query resolved.  Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle see edited query.  I now consider this (original) query resolved.  Thanks for your attention.

Comment: OK, glad you sorted out your issue, but you should close or delete the question as it can't be answered as posted

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think that the question should **not** be deleted, because it provides a handy reference; others may similarly "stub their toe".  **How do I close the question or request that the question be closed?**

Comment: @user2661923 a reference for what? it is not clear what you issue is but presumably not as the title suggests different fonts in article and book, nor is it clear what answer could be given. If you don't want to delete it you should remove the **resolved** section from the question and repost that as a self-answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Agreed, the title + original query were clearly erroneous.  I intend that the query should reference that I was **mistaken**.  A problem that seemed to originate from the use of the book class is actually a **printing** problem.  Further, the problem definitely involves latex and so this query (with my resolution) may be helpful to other latex users.  Also, I **agree** that it is not clear why my detail lines are printing too small.

Comment: Are you wanting a "List of Theorems" that would list the page numbers for each theorem?  Or are you wanting the statement of each theorem?  The former would be doable by either modifying a "List of Theorems" answer, or by reading the aux file from the main document.

Comment: @Teepeemm my bad for being unclear.  I am studying a textbook, and manually create a ch01.pdf (et al) for each chapter, which contains the solutions to all problems given by the book for each chapter.  I have found that it is best to create a summary.pdf as I study, that **lifts out** the pertinent definitions, theorems, key examples, and key problem statements.  This expedites my learning the material and attacking the subsequent problems.  Since the original material is a book that I bought, summary.pdf **must** be created manually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is deeper than I first imagined. After receiving replies, I attempted to create mwe's via pdflatex. During this attempt I noticed that the PDF rendering (e.g. qpdfview in fedora 29) was identical for both the book and article classes. Further, I (in effect) never print `ch01.pdf`, but print each page of `summary.pdf`, as it is ready.

During printing the detail lines of `summary.pdf` are too small. I use the `titlesec` package to precisely control the fonts used in the chapter, section and subsection headings. I need to somehow format the detail lines so that `summary.pdf` both prints okay and renders conveniently well in qpdfview.

The problem is clearly beyond the scope of this particular query, and might be beyond the scope of this forum. I am declaring the problem closed with respect to this query.

Comment: I saw your interaction with the user amWhy in mse meta. That [nasty](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8547) user has a notorious history of stalking and bullying people in meta. Be careful, and hope you do well.